# XCode keep search for flutter windows path

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I try to build IOS version to my flutter app

I'm using virtual box with macOC catalina

after edit flutter & app path in XCode like:

[image]

when I start to build app archive, XCode show this code
That mean its still looking for flutter windows path (C:\src\flutter..........)

[image: 2]

what's wrong here?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running your project in xcode
Do

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. go yo your iOS directory in side terminal and run pod install

And remember to run flutter commands you have to download flutter SDK (in your MacOs)

Comment: I had to remove Catalina OC and install BigSur to make the virtual machine updated
and do steps you say
Now I have skipped the previous error
but faced a new error :)
flutter_downloader not found

It seems that flutter with IOS is full of problems
any wI had to remove Catalina OC and install BigSur to make the virtual machine updated
and do steps you say
Now I have skipped the previous error
but faced a new error :)
flutter_downloader not found

It seems that flutter with IOS is full of problems
anyway thank you for your help